# Laravel Eloquent Query causes Application to continuously load

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I wrote the following eloquent query for a table in my application and now the application won't stop loading. what i need is to understand what is wrong with it and how to fix it

```
    $customer_purchased_1_time=DB::table("data as t1")->select('vin','last_service')
              ->where('type',1)->distinct('vin')
              ->whereRaw("(select count(*) from data where t1.vin=data.vin and data.type=1)=1")
              ->count();
```

It is the only code in my controller method along with the return statement. the incrementing of x was for debugging

Comment: Perhaps post the rest of the code as it looks like what you have above is inside a loop - the #1 suspect in "continuous loading" aka infinite recursion :-)

Comment: I will agree with @theruss. Also, it is a bit odd for you to increment `$x` both before and after the query.

Comment: Ha! didn't see that, good catch!

Comment: You are doing everything twice or thrice. You can remove ->whereRaw() completely because it's redundant. Same for $x temporary variable

Answer (score 0):

I solved it already. and this code worked fine for me

```
$customer_purchased_1_time=count(DB::table("data as t1")
              ->select('vin','last_service',DB::raw("count(*) as count"))
              ->where('type',1)
              ->distinct('vin')
              ->having("count","=",1)
              ->get());
```